# Linking error : undefined reference to `avahi_alternative_service_name'

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, avahi

in know i need to locate this symbol in library.. I am trying to compile avahi based test code to view services. But i am getting `undefined reference to`avahi_alternative_service_name'`.. I don't know which library contain this,I am running UBUNTU 12.04. I tried to install several packages but no success.. Any idea 
Thanks..

I have following packages installed

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep avahi
avahi-autoipd                   install
avahi-daemon                    install
avahi-utils                     install
libavahi-cil-dev                install
libavahi-client-dev             install
libavahi-client3                install
libavahi-client3:i386           install
libavahi-common-data            install
libavahi-common-data:i386       install
libavahi-common-dev             install
libavahi-common3                install
libavahi-common3:i386           install
libavahi-core7                  install
libavahi-glib-dev               install
libavahi-glib1                  install
libavahi-gobject0               install
libavahi-ui-dev                 install
libavahi-ui-gtk3-0              install
libavahi-ui0                    install
libavahi1.0-cil                 install
```

command 
`gcc -fpermissive testAvahi.c -o testAvahi`

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Show the command line used to compile/link - it may be as simple as having the library specified in the wrong place (It needs to be after any objects or libs that depend on it).

Comment: @twid, so you are not linking your compiled objects to any library. Do `gcc -o testAvahi testAvahi.c -l <avahi library>`. Check girish's answer to find out which avahi library provides the name required. If it is for example say libXYZ.a, your command should look like: `gcc -o testAvahi testAvahi.c -l XYZ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually needed to locate libraries and then needed to pass them to linker, So follwing command did work for me

`gcc -fpermissive  testAvahi.c -o testAvahi -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lavahi-client -lavahi-common`

Answer (score 1):

if you have a common folder where you place your c++ libraries you can check search for the function using the nm command
something like

```
cd /usr/lib
```

`nm -AC * | grep avahi_alternative_service_name`

The nm utility is available in binutils(sudo apt-get install binutils)